# Python NET init a jagged array

Tags: python, .net, jagged-arrays, python.net

I would like to init a .NET jagged array from Python using the pythonnet packages. For an one dimensional array I can do it like that:

```
import clr
from System import Array
a = Array[int]([1, 2, 3])
```

But how can I do that for jagged array? So let's assume I've in python the following list of list:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

In C# I would do it like that:

```
int[][] a = new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 }};
```

Comment: Wild guess here from *Nix land: `Array[Array[int]]([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`

Comment: relevant: https://grokbase.com/t/python/ironpython-users/095vyfwt24/ironpython-jagged-arrays so try: `Array[Array[int]]((Array[int]((1,2,3)), (Array[int]((4,5,6)))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `b = Array[Array[int]]([Array[int]([1,2,3]), Array[int]([4,5,6])])` works. But how can I write a python function that converts a jagged array which has n dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python it can be done like that:

```
b = Array[Array[int]]([Array[int]([1,2,3]), Array[int]([4,5,6])])
```

or if you define a helper function:

```
def asnetarray(x, defaulttype):
    if type(x) is list:
        if any([type(xi) is list for xi in x]):
            # Array of array
            return asnetarray([asnetarray(xi, defaulttype) for xi in x], defaulttype)
        elif x:
            # Array
            return Array[type(x[1])](x)
        else:
            # Empty array
            return Array[defaulttype]([])
    else:
        # Single element
        return Array[type(x)]([x])
```

then this can be used as:

```
# int[][]
b = asnetarray([[1, 2], [3, 4]], int)
# int[][][]
c = asnetarray([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]], int)
```